# Axios IE 11 issue, cannot download response type blob

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, axios

```
axios.get("http://localhost:63542/api/v1/WorkInst",
            {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/pdf'
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href= downloadUrl;
                a.download = ("test.pdf");
                a.click();


            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But instead of downloading, "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?" But it is working using google chrome and mozilla firefox. Badly need help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the [Download attribute](https://caniuse.com/#search=download) not support IE browser. So, in the IE and Edge browser, after getting the file data, you could use the msSaveOrOpenBlob method to download the file in IE and Edge browser, and in the Chrome or Firefox browser, you could create a hyperlink to download the file using the URL. More detail information, please check this sample:

```
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            //IE11 and the legacy version Edge support
            console.log("IE & Edge");
            let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/html" });
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {// other browsers
            console.log("Other browsers");
            var bl = new Blob([data], { type: "text/html" });
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
            a.download = fileName;
            a.hidden = true;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
```